# PHP : How to manage "Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content" error on simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, xml

**Language:** PHP 7.3 / Laravel 6.*

**Problem:** My system receive email from third parties that contain information about a potential customer. One of them send us data that contain UTF-16 tag but the content is UTF-8.

**Goal:** I want to let the system try the data as it receive it. Then, if an error occur, try something else. I don't want to change the UTF-16 string on every request.

**Code:**

```
$input = $request->all();
try {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($input['body-plain']);
    throw new Exception();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    try {
        $input['body-plain'] = str_replace("UTF-16", "UTF-8", $input['body-plain']);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($input['body-plain']);
        throw new Exception();
    } catch(Exception $e) {

    }
}
$prospect = $xml->prospect;
```

**Error:**

> simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content

```
    try {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($input['body-plain']); //This is the line where the error happen.
        throw new Exception();
```

**Data:**

```
...
  "body-plain" => """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
    <?ADF version="1.0"?>
    <adf>
    <prospect>
    <id source="language">Français</id>
    <requestdate>2019-11-20T11:35:24-05:00</requestdate>
    <vehicle interest="buy" status="Used">
...
```

**Conclusion:** I don't understand why the try catch don't work when I use it like that.
Is there a way I can tell PHP to look if the contain and label match?

Comment: Did you Google `Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content` and read a few of the results to see if they help yet?

Comment: I did. Most of the solution is to replace the string, like I do on the second try of the code. It's also why I have it, but as I mentioned, I don't want to do this on every request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML library used by PHP is not object-oriented and does not throw exceptions. In addition, you're throwing your own exception right in the code, ensuring the `catch` block gets executed every time.

Step one is to [disable libxml's error output](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php). Then [check for errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-last-error.php) and take appropriate action.

```
<?php
$input = $request->all();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($input['body-plain']);
$err = libxml_get_last_error();
// you'll need to confirm the error code, try `print_r($err);` here
if ($err->code === 5032) {
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $input['body-plain'] = str_replace("UTF-16", "UTF-8", $input['body-plain']);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($input['body-plain']);
}
if (libxml_get_last_error()) {
    // something bad happened
}
$prospect = $xml->prospect;
```

This info, along with a small example, can be found in [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php).